# What is the purpose of return statement in function decorator

Tags: javascript, function, return, decorator

I'm learning about decorators and I don't understand one thing - in every example, I came across there was a return statement at the end of a function. What is the purpose of that return statement? From my point of view, it's unnecessary, it doesn't even return anything.

```
    console.log('Hello, ' + name);
}

function loggingDecorator(wrapped) {
    return function() {
        console.log('Starting');
        const wrapper = wrapped.apply(this, arguments);
        console.log('Finished');
        return wrapper; // Why do I need this?
    };
}

const wrapped = loggingDecorator(doSomething);
wrapped('Rita');
const test = wrapped('Rita');
console.log(test); // undefined
```

Comment: Ah you mean the `return` for that "wrapper"; that's useful when the called function returns a value. That allows the logging wrapper to provide the caller with the same value that the actual (wrapped) function returns.

Comment: I thought so, but it was strange to me to see that over and over again in tutorials and blogs with reputation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without it, your decorator wouldn't forward along the return value from the wrapped function. Your `doSmething` doesn't return anything, so this behavior isn't being used, but if you tried to wrap a different function it would be needed.

```js
function doSomethingWithReturn(value) {
  return value.toUpperCase();
}

function loggingDecorator(wrapped) {
    return function() {
        console.log('Starting');
        const wrapper = wrapped.apply(this, arguments);
        console.log('Finished');
        return wrapper;
    };
}

const wrapped = loggingDecorator(doSomethingWithReturn);
const test = wrapped('Rita');
console.log(test); // 'RITA', but only because of the `return wrapper` statement
```